# Lodash to find if object property exists in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[ {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0"}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1"}, 
  {"name": "cat", "id": "cat_2"}
]
```

I want to insert another element, also named `apple`, however, because I don't want duplicates in there, how can I use lodash to see if there already is an object in the array with that same name?

Comment: `ARRAY.find(function(el){ return el.name === 'apple'; })` If `undefined`, There is no element in array having name as `"apple"`

Comment: @reectrix  `_.has(object, path)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what worked for me (after testing out the different solutions):

```
  addItem(items, item) {
    let foundObject = _.find(items, function(e) {
      return e.value === item.value;
    });

    if(!foundObject) {
      items.push(item);
    }
    return items;
  }
```

Answer (score 50):

You can use Lodash `_.find()` like this.

```js
var data = [ {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0"}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1"}, 
  {"name": "cat", "id": "cat_2"}
]

if(!_.find(data, {name: 'apple'})) {
  data.push({name: 'apple2'});
}
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Reference documentation: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#find

Comment: Link for _.find() documentation: [https://lodash.com/docs/#find](https://lodash.com/docs/#find)

Comment: this is not checking if property exists, but assumes property exists, and checks if has correct value. Wrong answer. Though a confusing question, guy asks one thing and then explains another

Answer (score 14):

This is Form

```
_.has(object, path)
```

Example:

```
const countries = { country: { name: 'Venezuela' } }
const isExist = _.has(countries, 'country.name')
// isExist = true
```

For more information [Document Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#has)

Comment: _.has tells about whether that path exists or not AND NOT about the value.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or lodash's `_.find()`:

```js
const addItem = (arr, item) => {
  if(!arr.find((x) => x.name === item.name)) { // you can also change `name` to `id`
    arr.push(item);
  }
};

const arr = [ 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0"}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1"}, 
  {"name": "cat", "id": "cat_2"}
];

addItem(arr, { "name": "apple", "id": "apple_0" });

addItem(arr, { "name": "pear", "id": "pear_3" });

console.log(arr);
```

And a bit shorter but less readable version:

```js
    const addItem = (arr, item) => arr.find((x) => x.name === item.name) || arr.push(item); // you can also change `name` to `id`

    const arr = [ 
      {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0"}, 
      {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1"}, 
      {"name": "cat", "id": "cat_2"}
    ];

    addItem(arr, { "name": "apple", "id": "apple_0" });

    addItem(arr, { "name": "pear", "id": "pear_3" });

    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: IMO, better to test it with ` === undefined`

Comment: Why - !undefined === true?

Comment: Readability is a good motive, but indeed it's a personal opinion. I'm going to add a shorter and less readable option :)

Comment: If it is an array as `[0,1,2]` and you are finding `0`, in that case `!0 === true;`, In this particular context, your approach is fine :)

Comment: Indeed you're right, but not when dealing with objects.

Comment: Yeah! `{}` is `truthy`!

Comment: HI @OriDrori again :"D can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189143/how-to-check-some-prop-in-object-equal-some-in-other-arrays)?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an other example with lodash

```
var a = [ {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0"}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1"}, 
  {"name": "cat", "id": "cat_2"}
]

var b = _.find(a, ['name', "apple2"]);

if(_.isObject(b)){
  console.log('exists')
}else{
    console.log('insert new')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/s4og07jg/

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in inserting in the array only one value, then using `_.find` could be an option. However, if you were interested in inserting one or more than one, I'd suggest using `_.unionBy` instead:

```js
var currentArr = [{
    "name": "apple",
    "id": "apple_0"
  }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "id": "dog_1"
  }, {
    "name": "cat",
    "id": "cat_2"
  }],
  arrayOneValue = [{
    "name": "apple",
    "id": "apple_0"
  }],
  arrayTwoValues = arrayOneValue.concat({
    "name": "lemon",
    "id": "lemon_0"
  })

console.log(_.unionBy(currentArr, arrayOneValue, 'name'));
console.log(_.unionBy(currentArr, arrayTwoValues, 'name'));
// It also allow you to perform the union using more than one property
console.log(_.unionBy(currentArr, arrayTwoValues, 'name', 'id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways of achieving this using `lodash` `4.17.5`:

Say you want to add object `entry` to an array of objects `numbers`, only if  `entry` does not exist already.

```
let numbers = [
    { to: 1, from: 2 },
    { to: 3, from: 4 },
    { to: 5, from: 6 },
    { to: 7, from: 8 },
    { to: 1, from: 2 } // intentionally added duplicate
];

let entry = { to: 1, from: 2 };

/* 
 * 1. This will return the *index of the first* element that matches:
 */
_.findIndex(numbers, (o) => { return _.isMatch(o, entry) });
// output: 0


/* 
 * 2. This will return the entry that matches. Even if the entry exists
 *    multiple time, it is only returned once.
 */
_.find(numbers, (o) => { return _.isMatch(o, entry) });
// output: {to: 1, from: 2}


/* 
 * 3. This will return an array of objects containing all the matches.
 *    If an entry exists multiple times, if is returned multiple times.
 */
_.filter(numbers, _.matches(entry));
// output: [{to: 1, from: 2}, {to: 1, from: 2}]


/* 
 * 4. This will return `true` if the entry exists, false otherwise.
 */
_.some(numbers, entry);
// output: true
```

If you want to return a `Boolean` (i.e., assuming that you are not using `_.some()`), in the first case, you can simply check the index value that is being returned:

```
_.findIndex(numbers, (o) => { return _.isMatch(o, entry) }) > -1;
// output: true
```

[`Lodash` documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#matches) is great source of examples and experimentation.