# How to check some prop in object equal some in other arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have two arrays
First one is static "Hardcode"
like this

```
 const days = [
    {
      id: 0,
      day: 'Saturday',
      morning: ['10:00', '12:00'],
      evening: ['2:00', '6:00'],
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      day: 'Sunday',
      morning: ['10:00', '12:00'],
      evening: ['2:00', '6:00'],
    },
    .... // to Friday
]
```

and the second array has come from API so i save it in state

response

```
 res = [{id: 10, day: "Sunday", morning: Array(2), evening: Array(2)},
{id: 11, day: "Monday", morning: Array(2), evening: Array(2)}] // hint: Ids not equals i will take Day name as a unick.
```

Now i have a checkbox the value of it is "true/false"
i want to compare if the response comes from API it's in the day's array "above" return true else false

so i make a function for it

I'm trying this also but not work and when I log `isExistDays(item.day) => undefined`

```
  let isExistDays = (name) => {
    daysSelected.forEach((el) => {
      return days.some((x) => x.day === name);
      // if (el.day === name) {
      //   console.log('yes', name);
      //   return true;
      // } else {
      //   console.log('no');
      //   return false;
      // }
      // return x;
    });
  };
```

and i render item callback "FlatList" i use that function to pass the name of the day

```
 const rnederDays = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <View style={styles.dayContainer}>
          <CheckBox
           
            value={isExistDays(item.day)} // here 
            onValueChange={(value) => {
              if (value === true) {
                let daysArr = {
                  id: item.id,
                  day: item.day,
                  morning: ['', ''],
                  evening: ['', ''],
                };
                setDaysSelected((prev) => {
                  return [...prev, daysArr];
                });
              } else {
                setDaysSelected((prev) => {
                  let deletedDay = prev.filter((day) => day.id !== item.id);
                  return deletedDay;
                });
              }
            }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.dayName}>{translateDay(item.day)}</Text>
        </View>
});
```

Now the problem is the function that's check exist name it returns **false** always!

> keep in mind: I want to use `daysSelected` again when i change the value of the checkbox, so i want to prevent duplicate :\

UI to understand // expected behavior here

[image: shot]

Comment: Wow man can you minimize?

Comment: @adirabargil What's the part you are miss?

Comment: I didnt read all cuz it began to be very long...

Comment: nevermind :) i solve it using this `value={daysSelected.some((dayName) => dayName.day === item.day)}`